# How would I set my textfield input to "0" or "1" if the user has selected a string from a pickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How would I set my textfield input to "0" or "1" if the user has selected a string from a pickerView? Here's the code  I have so far:

```
 if ([_businessTextField.text isEqualToString:@"User"]) { 
     NSString *userString = //set to "0"
 } else if ([_businessTextField.text isEqualToString:@"Business"]) {
     NSString *userString = //set to "1"
 }
```

Am I just going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `NSString *userString` declaration outside the conditional, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it after the `if`:

```
NSString *userString;
if (_businessTextField.text isEqualToString:@"User") {
    userString = @"0";
}else if (_businessTextField.text isEqualToString:@"Business"){
    userString = @"1";
}
// You can use userString's value here
_myTextField.text = userString;
```

Comment: Oh sorry, it said I couldn't mark it for another 9 minutes and I fell asleep shortly after. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

take bool as userstring instead of nsstring.